# Easiest way to work with Pandas rows that share same value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to come up with a fast and easy way to clean up a csv file. The file is formatted like this:

| Out_ClusterId | Out_Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 |  |

Basically, I was given a file with a list of businesses (names, addresses etc), and I matched it against what we have in our CRM database. The Out_ClusterId column matches all of the rows that are similar together. The Out_Id column will either have a unique id from the original file with the list of businesses, or it will be blank which means that the row is from our CRM database. Unfortunately the matching process we have creates a table that is a union of the original file and all of the account records in our database. Because of this, it not only matches between rows in the file and rows from the CRM, but it will also match against rows only from the CRM. These rows look like this:

| Out_ClusterId | Out_Id |
| --- | --- |
| 34 |  |
| 34 |  |

In this example the two rows with Id 34 are both matched from the CRM database because both have a blank Out_id. Any cluster of matches that don't have at least one record from the business file are irrelevant and need to be deleted from the output file. I have been trying to come up with a way to do so in Pandas, but I feel like my code is probably overly complex and cumbersome.

This is what I have so far in my code:

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'Dyn_Generic_Output.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding= 'unicode_escape')

df.sort_values(by=['Out_ClusterId'])

cluster_groups = df['Out_ClusterId'].unique()
cluster_groups_list = []
for i in cluster_groups:
    cluster_groups_list.append(i)

cluster_groups_dictionary = {}
for i in cluster_groups_list:
    cluster_groups_dictionary[i] = []
```

My next plan was to iterate over each row in the dataframe and if the Out_Cluster_Id matched the key in the cluster_groups_dictionary the Out_Id would be appended to that key's list. Then I was going to remove any key from the dictionary that had a blank list in it. Finally I was planning on  dropping every row from the dataframe that wasn't present in the remaining cluster_groups_dictionary. I feel like this is a bit over the top, but my understanding of python and Pandas is a bit elementary. Any feedback on how to do this more efficiently would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How are your blank `Out_Id` being represented? Are they NaN?

If they are, you can group by `Out_ClusterId` and count how many rows have a value for `Out_Id` in each group:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Out_ClusterId': [1,1,2,2,34,34], 'Out_Id':[2, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

df.groupby('Out_ClusterId').count()
```

|  | Out_Id |
| --- | --- |
| Out_ClusterId |  |
| - | - |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 34 | 0 |

You can then remove from your dataframe all rows that do not have a value for `Out_Id`:

```py
by_clusterId = df.groupby('Out_ClusterId').count().reset_index()
to_remove = by_clusterId[by_clusterId['Out_Id']==0]
df[~(df['Out_ClusterId'].isin(to_remove['Out_ClusterId']))]
```

|  | Out_ClusterId | Out_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2.00 |
| 1 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2 | 3.00 |
| 3 | 2 | NaN |